# Creating a register settings class that supports extended classes

Tags: plugins, settings-api, oop

I am having some trouble implementing a class structure to use for plugins I am developing. What I am trying to do is create a class I can just re-use for each plugin.

I want it to be able to be extendable so that if I need specific output to change I can just do so from that specific plugin and not have to worry about changing the base class(es).

The biggest issue I seem to be having is with calling the callback functions if they are located in another class.

Here is a general idea of what my base class is looking like:

```
class Register_Settings {

// This stores all the saved settings to fill in the form fields with saved values
protected $saved_settings = array();

...

// This for loop runs through the settings array that is passed in to create everything
foreach ( $options as $option => $v ) {
    add_settings_field(
        $section . '[' . $v['id'] . ']',
        $v['name'],
        method_exists( $this, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) ? array( $this, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) : array( $this, 'missing_callback' ),
        $section,
        $section,
        $this->get_settings_field_args( $v, $setting )
    );
}

...
}
```

This works great if I keep the callbacks in the base class. What I actually want to do is use another class for all of the callbacks though. Something like this:

```
class Register_Settings_Callbacks extends Register_Settings {

public function text_callback( $args ) {

    $value = $this->settings[ $args['id'] ];

    echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />';
}

...
}
```

Once I try to do this it stops working. The issue I know from the above examples is this line:

```
    method_exists( $this, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) ? array( $this, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) : array( $this, 'missing_callback' ),
```

I have tried doing several different things to fix this:

```
    method_exists( 'Register_Settings_Callbacks', $v['type'] . '_callback' ) ? array( 'Register_Settings_Callbacks', $v['type'] . '_callback' ) : array( 'Register_Settings_Callbacks', 'missing_callback' ),
```

This fixes some of the errors, but then I get some errors about the class being called statically and I don't want that.

That leads me to try something like this:

```
   $test_class = new Register_Settings_Callbacks();
```

which turns the questioned line into:

```
    method_exists( $test_class, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) ? array( $test_class, $v['type'] . '_callback' ) : array( $test_class, 'missing_callback' ),
```

This does get rid of all the errors, but when I do it this way my class variables don't get inherited.

Could this be because of a mistimed hook? Am I not understanding the variables passing over between the two correctly?

Any thoughts?

If you need to see more of my class then let me know and I can try and lay some more of it out.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Thanks to @toscho for getting me going in the right direction so far.

I have changed my trouble line above to this now:

```
    method_exists( new Settings_Callbacks( $this ), $v['type'] . '_callback' ) ? array( new Settings_Callbacks( $this ), $v['type'] . '_callback' ) : array( new Settings_Callbacks( $this ), 'missing_callback' ),
```

And my class that uses this is setup like this:

```
class Settings_Callbacks {

public function callback_A( $args ) { }

public function callback_B( $args ) { }

public function callback_C( $args ) { }

...
}
```

As pointed out below I opted not to use an Interface for this part because I don't want to redefine every function. What I instead want to do is have a base set of callbacks here that I commonly use for all my plugins, but if I need a specific functionality I can do something like this:

```
class Settings_Callbacks_Child extends Settings_Callbacks {

public function callback_D( $args ) { }

public function callback_E( $args ) { }

public function callback_F( $args ) { }

...
}
```

The problem with this boils back down to the callback function looking for a specific method. Since this is a child class it doesn't actually find the method in question, even if I have defined it here.

So I guess is there some way to check also for an unknown child class name and check it's methods as well?

Comment: Welcome to inheritance hell. Use [composition, not inheritance](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/response-private-methods-considered.html) when you want to write OOP.

Comment: Define "stops working" please. :)

Comment: @Rarst If it is all in one class then the options save and output correctly, but if I put it into two classes with the callbacks separated then the options no longer save or output correctly.

Comment: @toscho I just read the article you linked to and that's very interesting. Thanks for the link. So going by the article if I make an Interface I can just implement that instead of extending a class, is that how it works? I don;t have much experience with Interfaces. Thanks!

Comment: @NickYoung Yes, you pass an extra object for the callback handler into the main class.

Comment: @toscho Alright I tried doing the method similar to what you linked and passing the class object along works like a charm. I opted to not use interfaces though as I don't want to redefine each function for the extended classes. I am going to update my question a little bit to see if you might have any ideas how I can solve the next part of the issue I am having. Thanks so much for all your help so far - much appreciated!